# SQL Query in C# (Linq)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've this query in my C# file and it works fine:

```
from var in db.database_1 
where var.database_2.primarycat.Length > 0 && var.meditype.Contains("All")   
xxx               
select new XElement("id", new XElement("temp", var.database_2.name)
```

Now, I want to insert this query in the where argument at **xxx**:

```
AND name IN (
SELECT primarycat
from database_2
GROUP BY primarycat
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple sub query should do this:

```
from var in db.database_1 
where var.database_2.primarycat.Length > 0
    && var.meditype.Contains("All")   
    && (from cat in db.database_2
        group cat by cat.primarycat into g
        where g.Count() > 1
        select g.Key).Contains(var.name)
select new XElement("id", new XElement("temp", var.database_2.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub select. Check out this thread which answers pretty much the same thing.

[how to do subquery in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418609/how-to-do-subquery-in-linq)