# Convert a sql query with a subquery into a linq statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to do subquery in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418609/how-to-do-subquery-in-linq)

I have a SQL Server 2008 query:

```
select 
    account_hcc_id, account_name 
from 
    [ACCOUNT_HISTORY_FACT] 
where 
     TOP_ACCOUNT_KEY = (select TOP 1 TOP_ACCOUNT_KEY 
                        from ACCOUNT_HISTORY_FACT 
                        where account_hcc_id = '3362') 
     and ACCOUNT_LEVEL = 1;
```

I need to convert it to C# linq statement. Please let me know how could I do it.

Comment: [How to do a subselect in Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/q/418609)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from ahf in db.ACCOUNT_HISTORY_FACT
where ahf.ACCOUNT_LEVEL == 1 &&
      ahf.TOP_ACCOUNT_KEY == db.ACCOUNT_HISTORY_FACT
                               .Where(x => x.account_hcc_id == "3362") 
                               .Select(x => x.TOP_ACCOUNT_KEY)
                               .FirstOrDefault() 
select new { ahf.account_hcc_id, ahf.account_name };
```