# Restricting the set of objects returned by Include in EntityFramework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following tables and I want to return all the Sectors and any AvailableResources it contains.

[image: Sector-AvailableResources database diagram]

This would normally be simply a case of doing...

```
_dataContext.Sectors.Include(s=>s.AvailableResources);
```

...but I only want AvailableResources if they've not been released (ReleasedOn is nullable) or if the ReleaseOn date is in the future.

I'm almost certain that the only way I can do this in raw SQL is to join to a sub-query for AvailableResources but I want to do this using IDbSet collections (wrapping EntiyFramework 5).

Comment: Have you simply tried, `_dataContext.Sectors.Include(s=>s.AvailableResources.Where(q=>q!=null && q.ReleasedOn > DateTime.Now)`

Comment: I've tried that in LinqPad and I got the following `ArgumentException: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path`

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  I've never qualified an include -- worth a shot though.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up how to do sub queries in LINQ and found this answer. [how to do subquery in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418609/how-to-do-subquery-in-linq)

From that I tried this...

```
var context = new CSSDbEntities();

context.Sectors.Include(x=> x.AvailableResources)
    .Where(x=> !x.AvailableResources.Any() || context.AvailableResources.Where(ar=> ar.SectorId == x.SectorId && ar.ReleasedOn == null).Any());
```

Which seems to do the trick. I've got to add the `!x.AvailableResources.Any()` or it wan't to do an INNER JOIN and only returns sectors with resources.

Comment: Don't let this put you off from adding your own answer. I may be doing something totally daft here, the generated SQL doesn't look great.

Comment: Interestingly enough this works when working directly with the data context but not when working with my abstracted unit of work and IDbSet collections.