# Writing a subquery using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to query a DataTable that produces a DataTable that requires a subquery.  I am having trouble finding an appropriate example.
This is the subquery in SQL that I would like to create:

```
SELECT *
    FROM SectionDataTable
    WHERE SectionDataTable.CourseID = (SELECT SectionDataTable.CourseID
                                       FROM SectionDataTable
                                       WHERE SectionDataTable.SectionID = iSectionID)
```

I have the SectionID, iSectionID and I would like to return all of the records in the Section table that has the CourseID of the iSectionID.

I can do this using 2 separate queries as shown below, but I think a subquery would be better.

```
string tstrFilter = createEqualFilterExpression("SectionID", strCriteria);
tdtFiltered = TableInfo.Select(tstrFilter).CopyToDataTable();
iSelectedCourseID = tdtFiltered.AsEnumerable().Select(id => id.Field<int>("CourseID")).FirstOrDefault();

tdtFiltered.Clear();
tstrFilter = createEqualFilterExpression("CourseID", iSelectedCourseID.ToString());
tdtFiltered = TableInfo.Select(tstrFilter).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: This post might help: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418609/how-to-do-subquery-in-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it doesn't answer your question directly, what you are trying to do is much better suited for an inner join:

```
SELECT *
FROM SectionDataTable S1
   INNER JOIN SectionDataTable S2 ON S1.CourseID = S2.CourseID
WHERE S2.SectionID = iSectionID
```

This then could be modeled very similarily using linq:

```
 var query = from s1 in SectionDataTable
     join s2 in SectionDataTable
     on s1.CourseID equals s2.CourseID
     where s2.SectionID == iSectionID
     select s1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I tried your linq code and am getting a compile error that it does not recognize the 'join' keyword.  I am using System.Linq.  I am currently troubleshooting this error.

Comment: I figured it out.  I'm sure you were assuming I new more about LINQ.  But I didn't.  I needed to add the .AsEnumerable() to the DataTables.  This is final code:    `var query = from sectionTbl1 in TableInfo.AsEnumerable()
                            join sectionTbl2 in TableInfo.AsEnumerable()
                            on sectionTbl1.Field<int>("CourseID") equals sectionTbl2.Field<int>("CourseID")
                            where sectionTbl2.Field<int>("SectionID") == iSectionID
                            select sectionTbl1;`

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to figure it out Gloria!

Answer (score 0):

When working in LINQ you have to think of the things a bit differently. Though you can go as per the Miky's suggestion. But personally I would prefer to use the Navigational properties.

For example in your given example I can understand that you have at-least 2 tables,

1. Course Master
2. Section Master

One Section must contain a Course reference

Which means

One Course can be in multiple Sections

Now if I see these tables as entities in my model I would see navigational properties as,

```
Course.Sections    //<- Sections is actually a collection
Section.Course     //<- Course is an object
```

So the same query can be written as,

```
var lstSections = context.Sections.Where(s => s.Course.Sections.Any(c => c.SectionID == iSectionID)).ToList();
```

I think you main goal is, you are trying extract all the `Sections` where `Courses` are same as given `Section`'s `Courses`.

Comment: I would like to query a DataTable.  The DataTable binds to a gridview.  I don't know about Entity Framework. But what I am read, it would mean I would have to generate entities from the table.  I just want a simple query create a filtered DataTable of all of the sections with a CourseID.

Comment: I thought you are talking about Entity Framework which your question's Tag reflect.