# how to do subquery in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm a bit stuck on this. Basically I want to do something like the following SQL query in LINQ to SQL:

```
select Image from dbo.Employee where ID in(Select ID from dbo.Department where IsActive=1)
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do subquery in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418609/how-to-do-subquery-in-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the point with a subquery as in the question @IswantoSan links to ([how to do subquery in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418609/how-to-do-subquery-in-linq)) but, without knowing more about your entity relationships, why wouldn't simply use a join here?

```
from e in Employees
join d in Departments on e.ID equals d.ID
where d.IsActive
select e.Image
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Image from dbo.Employee
.Where(u =>
dbo.Employee
.Where(x => u.IsActive = 1)
.Select(x.ID)
)
```

Is the query that will work for you.