# How can I get all the children records in a single query if I need to lookup the parent ID?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a model with a parent - child relationship. `Year` and `Week`

```
Years: YearID, Name
Weeks: WeekID, YearID, Name
```

So if I have `YearSelected`, to get all the weeks from a year I do:

```
List<Week> weeks = db.weeks.Where(w => w.YearID == model.YearSelected).ToList();
model.WeekList = new SelectList(weeks, "WeekID", "Name");
```

But in DB I only save `WeekID` so only have `model.WeekSelected`

So How I get all the week of the same Year as `model.WeekSelected`

I can do a query first to get the YearID, but wonder if can do it in a single line.

```
int YearID = db.weeks.Where(w => w.WeekID == model.WeekSelected)
                     .SingleOrDefault().YearID.Value;
```

Comment: It would be better for everyone (you and the person coming after you who has to read your code) to do it in two lines instead of one.  Is there any compelling reason to do it in a single line?

Comment: In any case, what you're looking for is a subquery.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418609 and http://technologycraftsmen.net/blog/2010/04/21/how-to-subqueries-in-linq-to-sql/

Comment: @RobertHarvey is my understanding if I do separated line will need two call to db? so Is matter of performance.

Comment: It's two queries in either case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well that is weird. Cant you do a join or something? In regular sql you can do it is a single query.

Comment: ***If you're using Linq to Entities,*** it might be possible for the query engine in Entity Framework to optimize it.  The only way to know is try it both ways, look at the resulting SQL that is generated, and see what SQL Server's execution plan is for each.  My guess is that the subquery will actually de-optimize the generated SQL.  Note that you can chain `IQueryable`s together and they work the same way as if they were written as a single statement.

Comment: `In regular sql you can do it is a single query.` -- No, it's still two queries, though SQL Server *might* be able to perform some optimizations on the subquery.  Historically, subqueries are poor performers;  in practice, it's probably better to get the ID first, and then run your simpler query.

Comment: You can probably use join query. But when asking EF related question, it's better to post the sample entity classes, because the answer really depends on what navigation properties are available.

Comment: By the way, if your database is properly optimized with indices, the cost of getting that ID in its own query is very low.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The way I understand it, OP is asking for single database *trip*.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Yes, I know what he meant.

Comment: Software developers are notoriously bad at working out the relative performance of code just by looking at it.  Measure the performance of each approach, and then decide.

Comment: Also, note that you're not strictly limited to Linq to Entities for accomplishing this.  Entity Framework has an `ExecuteSql` method; executing raw SQL might work better in this particular scenario.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I think it's not about performance, but for convenience. To me the problem is not the goal, but looking to the problem as SQL. While with proper EF model, the answer would be simply `db.Weeks.Where(w => w.WeekID == model.WeekSelected).SelectMany(w => w.Year.Weeks)`

Comment: @IvanStoev: The *convenient* way is to use two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a sub-query to get the `YearID`:

```
List<Week> weeks = db.weeks
    .Where(w => w.YearID == db.weeks.First(w => w.WeekID == model.WeekSelected).YearID)
    .ToList();
```

This produces simpler SQL, not sure if it makes a performance difference, when you know `WeekSelected` only matches one row:

```
List<Week> weeks = db.weeks
    .Where(w => w.YearID == db.weeks.Single(w => w.WeekID == model.WeekSelected).YearID)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Wondering do you need do `First()` even if you know there is only one matching WeekID because is PK ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You could replace `First` with `Single` and get simpler SQL, but I am not sure it is faster.